# Laravel 5.6 How to pass URL as a URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Please any one could help me figure this out.

I have below URL for my route:

```
http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/http://localhost:8000/profile
```

And my route is:

```
Route::get('/notifications/{id}/read/{redirect_to}', 'NotiController@readAndRedirect');
```

This is throwing 404.

I have also tried with following:

```
Route::get('/notifications/{id}/read/{redirect_to}', 'NotiController@readAndRedirect')->where('redirect_to', 'some-regular-exp');
```

But it didn't worked.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Regards,
Jassi

Comment: This `http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/http://localhost:8000/profile` is generated from javascript at client side. Javascript has `encodeURI()` . I used `encodeURI('http://localhost:8000/profile')`. But it returns simply `http://localhost:8000/profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what others are suggesting here, perhaps consider instead of:

```
http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/http://localhost:8000/profile
```

To have the route look like:

```
http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/profile
```

And then prepend the `http://localhost:8000/` part in your code after handling the notification. Normally you don't want to redirect to a completely different host (I would assume), and it's potentially a security vulnerability (CSRF and such).

Comment: This sounds like a neat idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

It's because you can't have special characters in your URL.

Comment: This will never be able to work: `http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/http://localhost:8000/profile`. But if you rewrite that to this: `<?php echo 'http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/' . urlencode( 'http://localhost:8000/profile' ); ?>` then you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: This url is generated from javascript at client side. Javascript has `encodeURI()` .  I used `encodeURI('http://localhost:8000/profile')`. But it returns simply `http://localhost:8000/profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) strings that are put in an url. If not, characters like `/` or `?` might break your url.

```
echo 'http://localhost:8000/notifications/e343ec2f-9e3d-08df90e7030b/read/' . urlencode('http://localhost:8000/profile');
```